# Dart: How to programmatically add title to 'pop-up' window?

Tags: dart, dart-html

I've managed to display a programmatically created 'pop up' page with some buttons when a button on my main page is clicked/tapped but don't know how to display a title.  How do I do this and are there any other items I should set in HEAD? I'm a novice here.

```
btnToolsClicked(Event e) { 

  var content = 'Choose an Action <b>(Work In Progress)</b>'
    '<div id="menu-btns" class="radio-btns">'
      '<input id="B1" type="radio" name="radio-btn">'
        '<label id="lblB1" class="radiobutton-label" for="B1">&nbspExtract Thermal Data.</label><br>'
      '<input id="B2" type="radio" name="radio-btn" >'
        '<label id="lblB2" class="radiobutton-label" for="B2">&nbspCopy Data to USB drive.</label><br>'
      '<input id="BClose" type="radio" name="radio-btn" >'
        '<label id="lblClose" class="radiobutton-label" for="&nbspBClose">Close</label>'
    '</div>';


  JsObject w =
  context.callMethod("open",["","MsgWindow","width=640,height=480,top=100,left=100"]);

  JsObject doc = w['document'];
  doc['head']['innerHtML'] = '<title>Tools Menu</title>'; // FAILS
  doc['body']['innerHTML'] = content;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tested it but I would expect this to work:

```
  JsObject doc = w['document'];
  doc['title'] = 'Tools Menu';
```

Comment: This uses dart:js; is this the Dart way of creating a page on the fly?  I ask because I have not been able to register an onClick method.

Comment: You should be able to do these things with dart:html, there is no need for dart:js directly.